# Recursive function to find the position of a number (python)

Tags: python, list, recursion, position

I have this work (python) to do and I cannot think in a way to solve this problem.
Can anyone help me?

Make a recursive function that, given a list of ordered numbers and a number, returns the position of the element equal to the number or immediately higher than the number. To find the position, implement the binary search algorithm:

1- Compare the given number with the number of the central position of the list.

2- If the number is smaller, repeat the first step to the first half of the list.

3- If the number is higher, repeat the first step to the second half of the list.

4- Repeat the steps until an equal number is found or until the search region is reduced to only one element.

Comment: This looks like a homework question  that you didn't try to answer yet. If that isn't the case, it would be good to see what you have done so far as it would help us to see where you are having trouble. To get you started, here's an introduction to writing recursive functions in python: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Recursion

Comment: I've tried to do it but I couldn't. I have nothing to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know the steps. So its just a matter of implementing them. Find the central position and apply the steps.

```
def f(numbers, n, start, end):
    middle = (end-start) // 2
    if numbers[middle] == n:
        return middle
    if end - start == 1:
        return 'not found'
    if numbers[middle] < n:
        return f(numbers, n, start, middle)
    else:
        return f(numbers, n, middle, end)
```